# How to convert SQL query with IIF inside AND to work on MS SQL 2008 Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query which is Used in EXCEL Connection on data imported from CSV file which keeps changing on regular interval.
The Where Clause in Query is:

> "WHERE (ColumnA<-.4) AND (iif(ColumnB<500 And ColumnC>-900 And 
>       ColumnD>-900,0,1)>0) OR (iif(ColumnB<2000 And ColumnE+ColumnF>10000,1,0)>0)"

This above query works well inside Excel, now I Imported my CSV file to SQL 2008 Server.. but its not working due to iif function is not availble in 2008 server.

**I need help to convert this query to work on SQL 2008 Server.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor `IIF` as a [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) like below. This will work in all SQL Server versions.

```
ColumnA < -.4 
AND (
    CASE WHEN ColumnB<500 And ColumnC>-900 And ColumnD>-900 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END > 0
    OR CASE WHEN ColumnB<2000 And ColumnE+ColumnF>10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END > 0)
```

The searched form of the `CASE` expression used here evaluates the `WHEN` condition and returns the `THEN` value when true or the `ELSE` value of false. The `END` keyword indicates the end of the `CASE` expression.

Each `CASE` expression result in this query is checked to see if it's greater than zero. If either result is greater than zero (because of the `OR` logical operator) the predicate enclosed in parenthesis is true and evaluated with the other `WHERE` clause predicate (`ColumnA < -.4`).

Comment: Thank Dan, this is exactly what I was looking.. it did the job perfectly with slight modification I put OR in different Bracket..   Can you please explain the use of > (greater than sign) in this query, I am not able to understand this logic.   Many Thanks..

Comment: @AnilPatel, I added a link to the documentation and additional explanation.